# TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Router' in node

Tags: node.js, express

Hi I'm trying to follow this tutorial 
http://www.tokbox.com/blog/creating-chat-roulette-with-node-js-socket-io-and-opentok/

after successfully installed express, in my application folder I've updated code of Package.json file with below code as per tutorial

```
{
    "name": "RouletteTok",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "2.3.11",
        "jade": "0.12.1",
        "opentok": "0.1.0",
        "socket.io": "0.6.18"
    }
}
```

Then I ran the command in terminal **npm install** 
But When I was trying to run the node server by giving this command **node app.js** it gave me an error.
To be very Honest I got no idea about node js hence googled the error but couldn't figure it out. The error is as follow

```
/Users/UIMAC/RouletteTok1/routes/index.js:2
var router = express.Router();
                     ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Router'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/UIMAC/RouletteTok1/routes/index.js:2:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/UIMAC/RouletteTok1/app.js:8:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`express.Router` has been [added in express 4](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/New-features-in-4.x), set the express version in your `package.json` to `^4.0.0` and run `npm install`. Note that this might break some of your code because your current express version is really old.